# How to check InertiaRequest props with if else Vue Inertia Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

So I want to check if the `props` received from `HandleInertiaRequest` is null or not in my `v-if` from my vue component, but it always throws error like this

```
Navbar.vue:66 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at Proxy._sfc_render (Navbar.vue:66:46)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:816:16)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5701:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:19)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814:51)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822:5)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612:5)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565:9)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040:11)
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284:7)
```

I do it by using `v-if` like this

```
<div v-if="$page.props.auth.user.name">
                <p>{{ $page.props.auth.user.name }}</p>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <Link :href="route('login')">
                    <p class="btn btn-ghost">Sign in</p>
                </Link>
            </div>
```

but when the props is not null it succeeded doing the if statement, but when it is null it throws that error

I've already tried to use `isset` but it still throws an error

```
<div v-if="isset($page.props.auth.user.name)">
                <p>{{ $page.props.auth.user.name }}</p>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <Link :href="route('login')">
                    <p class="btn btn-ghost">Sign in</p>
                </Link>
            </div>
```

Comment: `v-if="$page.props.auth.user?.name"` perhaps? This way, if user is null, the v-if is negative and no exception is thrown.

Comment: ohhh thank you its work, please answer the question so I can mark it as answered

Comment: No, this same sort of question has been asked and answered too many times before. Best for you to either accept the duplicate or delete this very redundant question.

Comment: Okay I will delete this question, Thank you for commenting, I cant found the post that you suggested because  I dont know the keywords

Comment: correction: if user is null, the v-if is `false`, not "negative"

Comment: I guess I will accept the duplicate, incase someone have the same problem